# Unable to open a .avi file that I made using OpenCV

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv

So I decided to try making a screen recorder and I was following a [tutorial.](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/create-a-screen-recorder-using-python/)

So, the code works exactly as it should but after I finish the code and try running the .avi file I get the following error:

[image]

I searched around the web but I couldn't find the answer for my question, you guys have any idea?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

OpenCV uses FFMPEG under the hood and ships release builds without the proprietary codecs you often need.  I’ve been compiling OpenCV from source for 10 years and have successfully gotten good and repeatable codecs maybe once.  Here are my recommendations...

1. Did the video play in VLC?  That often is more forgiving.  Use VLC first to troubleshoot  the rest of your code if it plays there.
2. Play with many different FOURCC codes.  When using only free codecs, you have to iterate through a lot of them before finding a valid match.  Also, I’ve found that settings such as too low a frame rate can cause players to not work well.
3. Build a copy of FFMPEG from source with non-free drivers, then build OpenCV from source using those.  This is a rabbit hole of doom though cause each codec is itself a separate package and install.  You will spend a lot of time learning how to build software.
4. Use OpenCV for image processing and write video using a video writer API directly.  Libav/FFMPEG, libx264, and others all have direct callable APIs so you can use them.

Comment: I tried playing it on VLC but the video just starts and then suddenly stops.